# I want to draw on a canvas with a certain interval and setTimeout isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Here is the part of the code that matters:

```
function drawCircle(i, color1, color2) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                ctx.fillStyle = color1;
            }
            else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color2;
            }
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(110, 270, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(drawCircle(i, color2, color5), 4000);
}
```

Note that this is just a snippet I wanted to try out before I use code similar to this on a larger project. This isn't working properly, the image is only drawn once, that is, I only see the last circle that is drawn. I have googled this to death but nothing has helped me so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to use is `setInterval`. `setTimeout` just fires the event once. They have the same argument list.

Also I don't think the way you use `setTimeout` is correct. The way you've written it now, the function is fired before actually passing anything to `setTimeout`/`setInterval`. So you should write:

```
setInterval(function() {              // GOOD. An actual function is passed 
    drawCircle(...);                  // as the first argument.
}, 4000);
```

or:

```
setInterval('drawCircle(...)', 4000); // GOOD. the JS statement is supplied as 
                                      // a string and later on will be evaluated 
                                      // and executed with eval().
```

and **NOT**:

```
setInterval(drawCircle(...), 4000);   // BAD! drawCircle() is fired, its result 
                                      // evaluated and passed on to setInterval 
                                      // that doesn't know what to do with it.
```

**EDIT**

You don't have any blocking routines in JavaScript. It's a single threaded, event driven language. If you call something like `setInterval` it succeeds immediately. Only after 4 seconds or so your callback function will be invoked. However in the meantime JS will be busy doing all sort of different stuff - like for example reacting to other events generated by the user. What you want to do is to call `setTimeout` once and then inside the callback function, just before returning invoke it again with the same function and a different set of arguments of `i`. Something along these lines:

```
function drawCircle(i, ...) {

    // ... do stuff ...

    if (i < 10) {                    // Check if the callback has been invoked 10 
                                     // times already.
        setTimeout(function() {      // Schedule the callback for execution
            drawCircle(i + 1, ...);  // again after anoter 4 seconds.
        }, 4000);
    }
}

setTimeout(function() {              // Invoke the callback the first time 
    drawCircle(1, ...);              // after first 4 seconds.
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This works better, the site waits for four seconds, than draws the circle. But what happens after that is weird. The function drawcircle is called ten times in a row, with the same value for i, than waits for four seconds, and repeats the process.
Any idea as to why this is happening ? This is the first time I'm using loops in javascript as well as canvas, so pinpointing the error is kind of difficult.

Comment: To clarify, what I want to do is: for each run of the for loop, call the function drawcircle(...) and wait for four seconds. So the function should be called 10 times, with i ranging from 0-9 and the process should take 40 seconds.

Comment: I'll post my response in an EDIT.

Comment: This worked like a charm :) This is my first question here, and I'm really surprised by the responsiveness and quality of the answers. Thanks for, without a doubt, making me a regular here :) And of course thanks to the others who answered.

Comment: Yes I noticed but I hadn't created an account so I couldn't upvote. I've done so now, and I'll give the answer an upvote when I get the necessary "reputation". I have hit the tick mark as well. Thanks for the link on more info.

Comment: I might add : you can stop your loop by doing so `var intervalId=setInterval(function() { ... }, 100); clearInterval(intervalId);`

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a couple of things that are causing your code to misbehave, and they're all in how your loop is written. The first problem is the call to setTimeout, mainly that you're not passing a function object to it as the first argument, and most people would fix that by doing something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        drawCircle(i, color2, color5);
    }, 4000);
}
```

That will cause the setTimeout to delay as you expected, but it will end up calling drawCircle with 10 as the first argument 10 times, and that is because of every call is using the same reference to the "i" variable. The value for i isn't retrieved until the call is made...4 seconds or so after the loop completed when i is already 10.

To get around that, you need one more function:

```
function getDrawer(i, color2, color5) {
    return function() {
        drawCircle(i, color2, color5);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(getDrawer(i, color2, color5), 4000);
}
```

The getDrawer (a horrible name, please don't use it) function is called immediately, so the value of i is accessed immediately and remembered by the anonymous function that getDrawer returns. That anonymous function is what will be called by setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're calling setTimeout several times in a row, rather than calling it again from the callback. Try moving the call to `setTimeout` to the end of the `drawCircle` function to see the animation.